# User's balance not updating after deposit

Tags: php, laravel, api, coinpayments-api

I'm using [coinpayments](https://coinpayments.net) api for my laravel website and when the user deposits It should display in his ( $user->profile->deposit_balance) But it's not working. How Can i resolve my issue? Please commment if i'm providing less information. It's my first post :)

This is my deposit controller:

```
    public function create()
    {

        $gateways = Gateway::whereStatus(1)->get();

        $local_gateways = Offline::whereStatus(1)->get();

        $user = Auth::user();

        $settings = Settings::first();

        return view('user.deposit.create', compact('gateways', 'user', 'settings', 'local_gateways'));
    }
    public function cryptoConfirm(Request $request)
    {

        $gateway = Gateway::find(3);
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->nothing);
        $percentage = $gateway->percent;
        $fixed = $gateway->fixed;

        $charge = (($percentage / 100) * $request->amount) + $fixed;

        $new_amount = $request->amount - $charge;
        $publicKey=$gateway->val1;
        $privateKey=$gateway->val2;
        $cps = new CoinPayments();
        $cps->Setup($privateKey, $publicKey);
        $req = array(
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'currency1' => 'USD',
            'currency2' => $request->currency,
            'buyer_email' => $user->email,
            'buyer_name' => $user->name,
            'item_name' => 'Instant Deposit',
            'custom' => $request->nothing,
            'item_number' => $request->code.$user->id,
            'address' => '',
            'ipn_url' => route('userDepositCrypto'),
        );

        $result = $cps->CreateTransaction($req);

        if ($result['error'] == 'ok') {

            $deposit = Crypto::create([

                'amount' => $request->amount,
                'currency1' => 'USD',
                'currency2' => $request->currency,
                'details' => 'Instant Deposit Via Crypto Gateways',
                'transaction_id' =>$request->code.$user->id,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'gateway_id' => $gateway->id,
                'charge' => $charge,
                'amount2'=>$result['result']['amount'],
                'net_amount' => $new_amount,
                'status' => 0,
                'payment' => 0,

            ]);

            return redirect($result['result']['status_url']);

        } else {

            print 'Error: '.$result['error']."\n";
        }
    }


    public function cryptoStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $gateway = Gateway::find(3);

        $settings = Settings::first();

        $cp_merchant_id = $gateway->account;
        $cp_ipn_secret = $gateway->val3;
        $cp_debug_email = $settings->contact_email;
        function errorAndDie($error_msg) {
            global $cp_debug_email;
            if (!empty($cp_debug_email)) {
                $report = 'Error: '.$error_msg."\n\n";
                $report .= "POST Data\n\n";
                foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
                    $report .= "|$k| = |$v|\n";
                }
                mail($cp_debug_email, 'CoinPayments IPN Error', $report);
            }
            die('IPN Error: '.$error_msg);
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['ipn_mode']) || $_POST['ipn_mode'] != 'hmac') {
            errorAndDie('IPN Mode is not HMAC');
        }
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC'])) {
            errorAndDie('No HMAC signature sent.');
        }
        $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
        if ($request === FALSE || empty($request)) {
            errorAndDie('Error reading POST data');
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['merchant']) || $_POST['merchant'] != trim($cp_merchant_id)) {
            errorAndDie('No or incorrect Merchant ID passed');
        }
        $hmac = hash_hmac("sha512", $request, trim($cp_ipn_secret));
        if (!hash_equals($hmac, $_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC'])) {
            errorAndDie('HMAC signature does not match');
        }
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $amount1 = floatval($_POST['amount1']);
        $amount2 = floatval($_POST['amount2']);
        $currency1 = $_POST['currency1'];
        $currency2 = $_POST['currency2'];
        $status = intval($_POST['status']);
        $status_text = $_POST['status_text'];
        $crypto = Crypto::whereTransaction_id($item_number)->first();
        $user = $crypto->user;
        $gateway = $crypto->gateway;
        $order_currency = $crypto->currency1;
        $order_total = $crypto->amount;
        if ($currency1 != $order_currency) {
            errorAndDie('Original currency mismatch!');
        }
        if ($amount1 < $order_total) {
            errorAndDie('Amount is less than order total!');
        }
        if ($status >= 100 || $status == 2) {

            if ($crypto->payment == 0 ){

                $crypto->status = $status;
                $crypto->payment = 1;
                $crypto->save();

                $deposit = Deposit::create([
                    'transaction_id' => $item_number,
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'gateway_name' => $gateway->name,
                    'amount' => $request->amount,
                    'charge' => $crypto->charge,
                    'net_amount' => $crypto->charge,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'details' => 'Crypto Instant Deposit',
                ]);
                $user->profile->deposit_balance = $user->profile->deposit_balance + $crypto->amount;
                $user->profile->save();
            }
        } else if ($status < 0) {
            $crypto->status = $status;
            $crypto->save();
        } else {
            $crypto->status = $status;
            $crypto->save();
        }
        die('IPN OK');

    }
```

CoinPayments.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Robi;


class CoinPayments
{
    private $private_key = '***';
    private $public_key = '***';
    private $ch = null;

    public function Setup($private_key, $public_key) {
        $this->private_key = $private_key;
        $this->public_key = $public_key;
        $this->ch = null;
    }

    
    public function GetRates($short = TRUE) {
        $short = $short ? 1:0;
        return $this->api_call('rates', array('short' => $short));
    }

   
    public function GetBalances($all = FALSE) {
        return $this->api_call('balances', array('all' => $all ? 1:0));
    }

  
    public function CreateTransactionSimple($amount, $currency1, $currency2, $buyer_email, $address='', $ipn_url='https://www.sampleplatform.com/ipn-handler-script
') {
        $req = array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency1' => $currency1,
            'currency2' => $currency2,
            'buyer_email' => $buyer_email,
            'address' => $address,
            'ipn_url' => $ipn_url,
        );
        return $this->api_call('create_transaction', $req);
    }

    public function CreateTransaction($req) {
        // See https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc-create-transaction for parameters
        return $this->api_call('create_transaction', $req);
    }

    public function GetCallbackAddress($currency, $ipn_url = '') {
        $req = array(
            'currency' => $currency,
            'ipn_url' => $ipn_url,
        );
        return $this->api_call('get_callback_address', $req);
    }

    
    public function CreateWithdrawal($amount, $currency, $address, $auto_confirm = FALSE, $ipn_url = 'https://www.sampleplatform.com/ipn-handler-script
') {
        $req = array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'address' => $address,
            'auto_confirm' => $auto_confirm ? 1:0,
            'ipn_url' => $ipn_url,
        );
        return $this->api_call('create_withdrawal', $req);
    }
    public function CreateTransfer($amount, $currency, $merchant, $auto_confirm = FALSE) {
        $req = array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'merchant' => $merchant,
            'auto_confirm' => $auto_confirm ? 1:0,
        );
        return $this->api_call('create_transfer', $req);
    }

    
    public function SendToPayByName($amount, $currency, $pbntag, $auto_confirm = TRUE) {
        $req = array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'pbntag' => $pbntag,
            'auto_confirm' => $auto_confirm ? 1:0,
        );
        return $this->api_call('create_transfer', $req);
    }

    private function is_setup() {
        return (!empty($this->private_key) && !empty($this->public_key));
    }

    private function api_call($cmd, $req = array()) {
        if (!$this->is_setup()) {
            return array('error' => 'You have not called the Setup function with your private and public keys!');
        }

        // Set the API command and required fields
        $req['version'] = 1;
        $req['cmd'] = $cmd;
        $req['key'] = $this->public_key;
        $req['format'] = 'json'; //supported values are json and xml

        // Generate the query string
        $post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');

        // Calculate the HMAC signature on the POST data
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $this->private_key);

        // Create cURL handle and initialize (if needed)
        if ($this->ch === null) {
            $this->ch = curl_init('https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php');
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        }
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HMAC: '.$hmac));
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        $data = curl_exec($this->ch);
        if ($data !== FALSE) {
            if (PHP_INT_SIZE < 8 && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0) {
                // We are on 32-bit PHP, so use the bigint as string option. If you are using any API calls with Satoshis it is highly NOT recommended to use 32-bit PHP
                $dec = json_decode($data, TRUE, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
            } else {
                $dec = json_decode($data, TRUE);
            }
            if ($dec !== NULL && count($dec)) {
                return $dec;
            } else {
                // If you are using PHP 5.5.0 or higher you can use json_last_error_msg() for a better error message
                return array('error' => 'Unable to parse JSON result ('.json_last_error().')');
            }
        } else {
            return array('error' => 'cURL error: '.curl_error($this->ch));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I just noticed that I'm using `'auto_confirm' => $auto_confirm ? 1:0` I updated it to `'auto_confirm' => 1` in coinpayments.php Will it fix my issue?

Comment: What is the issue/error you get? That would be good for us to know and help you to answer the question.

Comment: @Arjan as i said when someone deposits the deposited amount should display in here : ( $user->profile->deposit_balance) But it's not working. It keeps showing 0

Comment: And what's the output of $crypto->amount? Does it show a value?

Comment: @Arjan the amount user will deposit

Comment: I meant If you debug, does it hold the actual value you expected it to be?

Comment: Problem is i can't check if the value actually exist. I don't see where the data is coming from....

Comment: Yes. it saves the amount in the cryptos table in db. problem is the status is not updating.